# PrimeFaces Sheet component movable columns

Tags: jsf, primefaces, handsontable, primefaces-extensions

I have the following issue with PrimeFaces Sheet Component. I have moveble columns and rows. To some columns i have sortBy and filterBy. So, when i move one column, which doesn't have sortBy for example, by moving it the sortBy stays on its place and the previous column takes it. Which is wrong.

Do you have any idea how can i avoid this behaviour?

```
 <pe:sheet id="sheet" widgetVar="sheetWidget" value="#{vertragspreiseForm.lazyModel.getPreiseList()}" var="row"
        rowKey="#{row.pflegeartId}"
        height="400"
        resizableRows="true"
        resizableCols="true"
        fixedCols="2"
        showColumnHeaders="true"
        movableCols="true" movableRows="true">
```

Comment: Its most likely a bug as I have never tried or tested these features working together.  Feel free to report the bug here: https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions

Comment: Hello, many Thanks! Yes, because when i remove the sortBy and findBy, then it works fine.  Since i add them, it works not as i expect. The headers are moved as suppouse to, but the sort field stays on it previous place.

Comment: https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions/issues/911